# Make a type be either one type or another

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell playing around with parsing and building an AST. I wonder how one would go about defining types like the following:

A `Value` can either be an `Identifier` or a `Literal`. Right now, I simply have a type `Value` with two constructors (taking the name of the identifier and the value of the string literal respectively):

```
data Value = Id String
           | Lit String
```

However, then I wanted to create a type representing an assignment in an AST, so I need something like

```
data Assignment = Asgn Value Value
```

But clearly, I always want the first part of an `Assignment` to always be an `Identifier`! So I guess I should make `Identifier` and `Literal` separate types to better distinguish things:

```
data Identifier = Id String
data Literal = Lit String
```

But how do I define `Value` now? I thaught of something like this:

```
-- this doesn't actually work...
data Value = (Id String)  -- How to make Value be either an Identifier
           | (Lit String) -- or a Literal?
```

I know I can simply do

```
data Value = ValueId Identifier
           | ValueLit Literal
```

but this struck me as sort of unelegant and got me wondering if there was a better solution?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [GADTs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT). Since both `Id` and `Lit` are based on `String` now you might want to parametrize the type with something extra to distinguish between the two (perhaps a phantom type variable).

Comment: I don't think `data Value = ValueId Identifier | ValueLit Literal` is unelegant. What do you not like about it? — BTW, note that normally we prefer to write `newtype Identifier = Id String`, rather than the `data` equivalent. It's a bit more efficient (`data` always makes an additional layer of thunk indirection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first tried to restructure my types so that I would be able to do it with GADTs, but in the end the simpler solution was to go leftroundabout's suggestion. I guess it's not that "unelegant" anyways.